# Archivo de propiedades Properties. Problemas con classpath

Tags: java, archivo-de-propiedades

Tengo mi clase `Propiedades`. Para cargar el archivo `properties` uso el método `loadConfig()` que funciona bien pero me falta el método `setPropertyValue()`. Cómo busco el classpath?.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Propiedades {
    private static Properties config;
    private static InputStream configInput;

    public Propiedades() {
        config = new Properties();
        configInput = null;
    }

    public String loadConfig(String nomProp){
        try{
            config.load(this.getClass().
                getResourceAsStream("/propiedades/config.properties"));          
        } catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error cargando configuración\n" + e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        return config.getProperty(nomProp);
    }
    public void setPropertyValue(String property, String value){

       config.setProperty(property, value);
       try
       }
           //config.store() en este método debo indicarle el classpath
       }
       catch(IOException ex)
       {
           Logger.getLogger(Propiedades.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los métodos de `Operaciones` que llaman:

```
public static String getValorPropiedad(String nombreProp){
    return prop.loadConfig(nombreProp);
}
public static void setValorPropiedad(String nombreProp, String valorProp){
    prop.setPropertyValue(nombreProp, valorProp);
}
//prop es estática, la declaro como atributo de `Operaciones` y la instancio en el constructor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(this.getClass().getResource("/propiedades/config.properties").getFile()));
            config.store(out, null);
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107260/discussion-on-answer-by-angeldev-archivo-de-propiedades-properties-problemas-co).